# NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.app.Fragment.mContainerId' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Having some interesting issue with transaction on fragments on Android Lollipop ONLY. Crash happens when i go back and remove previously added fragment.

Here is stacktrace :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.parkme.consumer, PID: 15560
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.app.Fragment.mContainerId' on a null object reference
    at android.app.BackStackRecord$1.onPreDraw(BackStackRecord.java:1131)
    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1970)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

How i am doing transaction :

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.list_holder, listFragment)
            .commit();
```

R.id.list_holder

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

How i remove it :

```
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .remove(listFragment)
            .commit();
```

And I`m receiving the crash on last code fragment.

UPDATE

After i had removed it has no crashes anymore:

```
Transition slideTransition = TransitionInflater.from(ParkmeApplication.getContext()).inflateTransition(R.transition.slide_right);
setExitTransition(slideTransition);
```

slide_right :

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <slide
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:slideEdge="right"/>
</transitionSet>
```

Comment: Why are you removing the fragment explicitly instead of adding it to backstack?

Comment: @MohammedAtif There are some other code lines to do specific changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deal was in to do not use `getFragmentManager()` method and use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead and extend from `v4.app.Fragment` class.
 After i have been moved out from `android.app.Fragment` it is working now without crashes.

So my recommendation for all if you have such uses of `getFragmentManager()` and you have anyone support libraries used in your app then just move to support manager. Even it`s working for you. Or you can hit the crash with some strange bug as i did. Thanks to all who got time to give me advices !

Comment: I'm facing same kind of issue. can you please provide me more information.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error while doing Fragment Transaction on Fragment which does not exist in `FragmentManager`:

`fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("MyTag"));`

Fragment with "MyTag" does not exist in `FragmentManager`, so `FragmentTransaction` tries to do job on null Fragment.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem. you save my time (y)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to remove null from fragment manager.

This was the actual code:

```
broadcastFragment = null;
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(broadcastFragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

The replace function removes previously added fragments at R.id.list_holder and adds in the new fragment. So, when you remove your fragment, the system can't find it since it's already been removed by the replace function.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue and I was wrongly to call `addToBackStack()` when adding first fragment into the layout. Have removed it and it works well.
Obvious is that it's working in higher Android level such as `O`.